# Arrangements around a circular table with people sitting together

Tags: combinatorics

A group of $n$ people sit around a circular table. How many arrangements are possible if $ k \ $people sit together?

I am thinking $(n-k)!k!$ but I might be wrong. Please help!

Comment: It's right! why do you think might be wrong?

Comment: Could you explain why? @Amir

Comment: Give $k$ people sit together as a person then you wanna sit $(n-k+1)$ sit around a circular table $(n-k+1-1)!$ way. and and k people should sit together $k!$ then your answer is right!